# cpanel awstats redirection automatically

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to implement to show the awstats page of cpanel. I would like to automatically login to cpanel and then show the awstats of the passed domain. I used the following code for this, but it seems going to login page and not showing the awstats page

```
$cp_user = "<username>";
$cp_pwd = "<password>";
$url = "https://xxxx:2083/login";
$cookies = "cookies.txt";

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies); // Save cookies to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$cp_user&pass=$cp_pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100020);

$f = curl_exec($ch);
$h = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($f == true and strpos($h['url'],"cpsess"))
{
  // Get the cpsess part of the url
 $pattern="/.*?(\/cpsess.*?)\/.*?/is";
 $preg_res=preg_match($pattern,$h['url'],$cpsess);
}

$token= $cpsess[1];
header('Locations: https://xxxx:2083'.$token.'/awstats.pl?config=<domain>&ssl=&lang=en');
```

Is there anything wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought I would throw out an answer since no one else has responded. Maybe it will help someone else trying this too.

The reason you're not able to get this working is because cPanel validates the IP address of the user. Your cURL script is housed on your server with its IP, and the user trying to login has their own IP address.

Check out the cPanel (x3) login form, there's not even a form field to submit your IP address, so it's being retrieved solely on the server side to prevent spoofing.

```
 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=myuser&pass=mypass");
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
 $body = substr($result, $header_size);
 curl_close($curl);

 $header = str_replace("\r", '', $header);
 $header = explode("\n", $header);

 foreach ($header as $h) {
     header ($h);
 }
 $parts = explode( 'URL=', $result);
 $session_parts = explode( '/frontend/', $parts[1]);
 $token = $session_parts[0];

 header('Location: http://ss.com:2082'.$token.'/awstats.pl?config=ss.com&ssl=&lang=pt');
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi Chauhan for the reply, so,  which means there isn't any ways to achieve this ?